# reading content of arraybuffer in javascript send via server (file reader api)

Tags: javascript, python, flask, flask-socketio

When I am sending blob to server
but when i am sending it back to client using `emit()` of socketio library  it is converted to ArrayBuffer(2563)

```
[[Int8Array]]
:
Int8Array(2563) [100, 105, 115, 116, 114, 105, 98, 117, 116, 105, 111, 110, 32, 118, 115, 32, 118, 97, 114, 97, 98, 108, 105, 116, 121, 32, 32, 111, 114, 32, 115, 116, 97, 110, 100, 97, 114, 100, 32, 100, 101, 118, 105, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 13, 10, 13, 10, 13, 10, 115, 99, 97, 108, 101, 32, 111, 102, 32, 115, 99, 97, 116, 116, 101, 114, 32, 112, 108, 111, 116, 13, 10, 108, 105, 110, 110, 101, 114, 32, 112, 97, 116, 116, 101, 114, 32, 111, 102, 32, 108, 105, 110, 101, 32, 105, …]

[[Uint8Array]]
:
Uint8Array(2563) [100, 105, 115, 116, 114, 105, 98, 117, 116, 105, 111, 110, 32, 118, 115, 32, 118, 97, 114, 97, 98, 108, 105, 116, 121, 32, 32, 111, 114, 32, 115, 116, 97, 110, 100, 97, 114, 100, 32, 100, 101, 118, 105, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 13, 10, 13, 10, 13, 10, 115, 99, 97, 108, 101, 32, 111, 102, 32, 115, 99, 97, 116, 116, 101, 114, 32, 112, 108, 111, 116, 13, 10, 108, 105, 110, 110, 101, 114, 32, 112, 97, 116, 116, 101, 114, 32, 111, 102, 32, 108, 105, 110, 101, 32, 105, …]
byteLength
:
(...)
```

I have upload text file send to server and in console this was file return by server, so how to read the file content, I have used filereader API and converted it to blob and then server has send it to me as arraybuffer.

when file was in file I was able to read its content directly on client side
when I send it to server in python the blob file I was able to read it too, by print but when it was send back to client arraybuffer, I don't know how to view its content.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a [Blob from an ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob#Syntax), you can then run that Blob through FileReader to get the text

```
var blob = new Blob([yourArrayBuffer]);
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function(){
  console.log("text: ",reader.result);
};
reader.readAsText(blob);
```